# Pre-requisites to learn node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to learn Node.js. I'm sure, I will need good experience in Javascript (OOP). Is there any other technology i should know about to learn it? And also how long will it take me to starting implementing node.js taking into account i have decent experience in Javascript?

Thank You

Comment: You do not need OOP knowledge for it. Good JavaScript experience and being at least a bit smart should be sufficient.

Comment: So, basic client side javascript experience is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

> JavaScript is a class-free, object-oriented language, and as such, it
>   uses prototypal inheritance instead of classical inheritance. This can
>   be puzzling to programmers trained in conventional object-oriented
>   languages like C++ and Java. JavaScript's prototypal inheritance has
>   more expressive power than classical inheritance, as we will see
>   presently.

Javascript and Java are two different beasts.

> I have been writing JavaScript for 8 years now, and I have never once
>   found need to use an uber function. The super idea is fairly important
>   in the classical pattern, but it appears to be unnecessary in the
>   prototypal and functional patterns. I now see my early attempts to
>   support the classical model in JavaScript as a mistake.

---

Some things I think you should look into.

- Testing your code thoroughly with framework like for example [mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha) is very important.
- learn [npm](http://npmjs.org/) to publish your own modules and to [search](http://search.npmjs.org/) for other modules.
- A database like for example mysql, mongodb or [redis](http://redis.io) and how to use them in node.js. I pesonally really like [redis client library](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) for it's insane speed.
- [Git(hub)](http://github.com) to put your code into a repository(SCM).

Answer (score 0):

Except from all kind of JavaScript programming experiences (OOP is not required) and depending from your former programming skills it also helpful to have a basic knowledge of:

- the Posix API (what are file descriptors? what are pipes?)
- what is HTTP? How does HTTP work?